# ¿Por qué es 'la' al respecto de 'amor' (El burlador de Sevilla​ de Tirso de Molina)? ¿Es un error?

Tags: gramática, concordancia-gramatical

En la jornada primera [*El burlador de Sevilla*](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/El_burlador_de_Sevilla/Acto_I)​ de Tirso de Molina, el Rey dice:

> No importan fuerzas,
> guardas, criados, murallas,
> fortalecidas almenas,
> para amor, que **la** de un niño
> hasta los muros penetra.

¿Por qué **la** al respecto de **[amor](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/amor#Sustantivo_masculino)**? ¿Es un error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se refiere a **la fuerza**, no al amor

Transcrito de otro modo:

> No importan fuerzas, (guardas, criados, murallas, fortalecidas almenas)
> para amor, que la de un niño hasta los muros penetra.